# Error while deploying dashboards

Tags: dashboard

We are getting the below error while trying to push the dashboard from one org to another one..

Does have anyone have  any idea on this error..Appreciate your help..

"Must specify sortBy attribute to one dashboard table column"

Answer (score 2):

To debug which dashboard is causing issue try to run all the dashboards you are moving from one instance to the other Instance .

I am sure there is one report which you are using as dashboard and you have not sorted alteast one column before using in dashboard .

So one by one verify that all your dashboards display properly on your source org instance ,I suspect all have not compiled .